# Retrofit: what is different between @Field and @Body

Tags: android, post, retrofit

In some post request, I don't know when to use @Field, when to use @Body.
Like whats the difference between:

```
@POST("users/register")
    Call<String> register(@Body RequestBody registerRequest);
```

and:

```
@POST("users/register")
    Call<String> register(@Field String id, @Field String pass);
```

Can I use @Body instead of @Field, and reverse ? If not, why ? And how to know this case use @Body, other case use @Field ?

Can you please give me some case and explain, thank you.

Answer (score 44):

`@Body` – Sends Java objects as request body.

`@Field` – send data as form-urlencoded. This requires a `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation attached with the method.
The `@Field` parameter works only with a POST. `@Field` requires a mandatory parameter. In cases when `@Field` is optional, we can use `@Query` instead and pass a null value.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still confusing about can use Body instead of Field, and reverse ?

Comment: No.  If @ Body is being used, it should be the only parameter and it can not be combined with @FormUrlEncode or @ MultiPart.

Comment: I want to know why ? and how to know in some case use @ Body, in other case use @ Field ?

Comment: in which cases @Field is optional and in which case its mandatory?

Comment: Copy pasted from:
https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial

Answer (score 33):

Both are used for posting data only, but they have following difference -

The @Body annotation defines a single request body.

```
    interface Foo {
       @POST("/jayson")
       FooResponse postJson(@Body FooRequest body);
    }
```

That means if you are using @Body, it should be only parameter. It is helpful when you have already a JsonObject and you want to send it as it with you api call.

Another way is, you can send data using @Field and send the Place object as a JSON string.

```
    @POST("/post/addphoto/")
    public void addImage(@Field("image_url") String url, @Field("caption") String caption, @Field("google_place_id") String placeId, @Field("facebook_place") String place, Callback<UploadCallBack> response);
```

Hope it will help... :-)

Comment: it will be great if you print resulting url