# Retrofit posts empty data

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm new to Retrofit. 
I simply add a row to my database with using retrofit but i used field parameters in my api interface like this.

```
Call<String> matchWith(@Field("fbid") String fbid, @Field("matchwith") String matchwith);
```

It is hard to write for big objects so i decided to use `@Body` annotation. But now its posting empty row/object in my mysql database. (With `@Field` annotation in api interface my code inserts the data correctly)

Here is my code

```
@POST("/insertuser.php")
Call<User> postUser(@Body User user);



Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://myurl.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Connect connect = retrofit.create(Connect.class);

    Call<User> call = connect.postUser(user);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

In my object class i used `@SerializedName` and `@Expose` retrofit still inserts empty I have tried with just `@SerilizedName` and just with `@Expose` after that I used nothing but I got same result.

Comment: could it be that 'user' is just empty?

Comment: No user object is not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is difference between `@Field` and `@Body` annotations. Your API might be accepting data as `form-data` only. That is why your data is considered as empty data when you send it through request body i.e. using `@Body` annotation.

You can change your web API to accept data as request body and then use as your are using.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43337183/4387543)

Comment: I updated my api for accepting the body. Now i can insert my data thanks.

Comment: Emre Akcan, I try to understand, but I can't... what does it exactly mean "update the api for accepting the body"?

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient=new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);**


        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();
        }
```

Now you can see if you send the correct data and server responses correctly, otherwise search the problem in server

Comment: there is no method like addInterceptor where should i add this method?
`retrofit.addInterceptor` is not acceptable

Comment: You can add that intercepter in your OkHttp Client.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sending the request correctly problem is my api doesn't accept the body.Its explained in above answer.